# Send pointer to a function

Tags: c++, pointers

I want to send a pointer to a function, my problem is that when I try sending the memory address of the pointer to the function, it force me to declare the arguments of the second function like **.

```
void MaterialParser::processMaterialTexture(vector<string>* params, MaterialTexture* texture){
    for (int i = 0; i < params->size(); i++){
        if((*params)[i]=="-o"){
        proccesOST(&texture,&params,i);
        }
     }
     }
void MaterialParser::proccesOST(MaterialTexture* texture ,vector<string>* params,int index){
//function
```

When I call the funcion, throws the following error, the argument MaterialTexture** is not compatible with a parameter MaterialTexture*.

```
proccesOST(&texture,&params,i);
```

If I declare the function like:

```
void MaterialParser::proccesOST(MaterialTexture** texture ,vector<string>** params,int index){
```

How can I access to the variables? or better, how can I send the arguments to be only a pointer and not a double pointer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`texture` already is of type `MaterialTexture*`; and the same goes for params. So no need to put an `&` in front of it when you pass it to the other function.

Just write

```
proccesOST(texture, params,i);
```

To clarify why: With the `&` operator, you take the address of something. If that something, as in the `&texture` case, is already a pointer, you get the address of the pointer; and the type which can hold that is a pointer to a pointer. Think of it this way: For each time you add a `&` in front of a variable, you'd also have to add a `*` to the type being able to hold the result.

Answer (score 2):

Omit the & in the function call. Your texture is already a pointer. The & operator creates a pointer to what's behind it, which you don't want to do in this case.